# Simplified guide on when to use before/after and for each row/statement triggers

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

Considering Postgres as Dbms:

-Always use Before Trigger unless you need a specific information that can be obtained only after a record has been inserted or in rare cases updated.

-Always use for each statement unless you need a specific information of a specific row.

Is this correct? Or are there situations where what I wrote is not valid?

Comment: An full answer would be very long. Look at the Notes section of [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and the [Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) section of plpgsql. They will tell you the various limitations/options. Basically you need to figure out what you want to accomplish with a trigger first, then create the appropriate form.

Comment: I read the official documentation but this is about making a very simplified guide based on questions you want to ask yourself before writing a trigger to decide which one to use. Questions like: Do I need informations about a new inserted row when considering the trigger conditions? Of course there may be some very specific cases where general rules don't apply, but the post is about simplify the use cases rules as much as possibile.